# Symfony 5 console command - problem with constructor with parameter

Tags: php, command-line, symfony5

I have a problem with **console's command** in Symfony 5. 
I try to pass one parameter in constructor's command (**TerytWMRODZRepository $terytwmrodzrepo**), because I want to connect with database and exec queries. One way to do this is create repository to entity, and I done this. But when **I put parameter in constructor's command**, I have error. 
Below code this console's command:

```
# src/Command/GetNewDataTerytCommand.php
# ...
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Httpfoundation\Response;
use App\TERYT_SoapClient;
use App\Service\DB\TerytDB;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\LockableTrait;
use App\Repository\TerytWMRODZRepository;

class GetNewDataTerytCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $wsdl = 'https://uslugaterytws1test.stat.gov.pl/wsdl/terytws1.wsdl';

    private $terytwmrodzrepo;

    protected static $defaultName = 'teryt:get';

    public function __construct(TerytWMRODZRepository $terytwmrodzrepo){

        $this->terytwmrodzrepo= $terytwmrodzrepo;

        parent::__construct();
    }
    ...
}
```

When I use console's command in terminal: **'php bin/console teryt:get'**, I have output like:

ArgumentCountError {#67

```
  #message: "Too few arguments to function App\Command\GetNewDataTerytCommand::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/umowy_uzytkownicy/bin/console on line 43 and exactly 1 expected"<br />
  #code: 0<br />
  #file: "./src/Command/GetNewDataTerytCommand.php"<br />
  #line: 27<br />
  trace: {<br />
    ./src/Command/GetNewDataTerytCommand.php:27 {<br />
      App\Command\GetNewDataTerytCommand->__construct(TerytWMRODZRepository $terytwmrodzrepo)<br />
      › <br />
      › public function __construct(TerytWMRODZRepository $terytwmrodzrepo){<br />
      › <br />
    }<br />
    ./bin/console:43 { …}<br />
  }<br />
}<br /><br />
```

I tried find solution in **documentation's Symfony 5** on url:https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/commands_as_services.html and other pages like: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1131/how-to-access-the-entity-manager-doctrine-inside-a-command-in-symfony-5
but nothing working.

I tried in **config/service.yaml** configure console's commands as service but nothing changed:

```
# config/services.yaml
# ...
services:
    ...
    App\Command\GetNewDataTerytCommand:
        public: true
        tags:
           - { name: 'console.command', command: 'teryt:get'}
```

PS: I apologize for my English. This is my first question in StackOverFlow.

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you using the default services documentation and autowiring? If not, you'll have to manually register your command as a service and define the dependency it takes as an argument.

Comment: I tried this and that. Nothing changed and I have still error (I added autowiring in config/services.yaml in three dotes as: _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true)

Comment: It seems to me that by default `Repository` folder is `exclude` form service autodefinition. You will probably need to define a new service for your repository.

Comment: @GrenierJ That would be quite contrary to the documentation which states that the default is `exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'`. Michał, can you check if this setting has been modified in your project?

Comment: @El_Vanja sorry I didn't see the version of symfony. Because in [symfony 3.4 documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container), it's excluded. But since symfony 4 it's not more excluded.

Comment: El_Vanja yes, I modified because I have this error. I tried add next elements to this and at the moment I have: `exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Command,Repository,ServiceEntityRepository,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}` but I have still error. Even I would removed them nothing change. To my mind problem is in another place.

Comment: When you run `bin/console debug:container TerytWMRODZRepository` ( command to list all services with name `TerytWMRODZRepository`. Did you have something ? If you have nothing, you can't use `dependency injection`

Comment: If I have one parameter in constructor GetNewDataTerytCommand, I have error: 'Too few arguments to function App\Command\GetNewDataTerytCommand' etc. If I remove this parameter and run `php bin/console debug:container TerytWMRODZRepository`, I have `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\InvalidArgumentException] No services found that match "TerytWMRODZRepository" ` even if I add `TerytWMRODZRepository` in `exclude` in services.yaml

Comment: You must not add it in exlcude, else it's normal that you get no service.

Comment: Yes, I know. I removed my elements from 'services.yaml' and I have exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}' . Run your command I got: Service ID App\Repository\TerytWMRODZRepository
Class App\Repository\TerytWMRODZRepository
Tags doctrine.repository_service
Public yes
Synthetic no
Lazy no
Shared yes
Abstract no
Autowired yes
Autoconfigured yes

Comment: SO now, the command should work

Comment: @GrenierJ yep, without parameters in constructor this command works wonderful. But if I would put parameter from class TerytWMRODZRepository to the constructor this command, I got old error "Too few arguments...". I need by console's command exec query on database, if you know another solution by do this, please describe me

Comment: Really stange, since the service `TerytWMRODZRepository` is autowired. THis repository extends from `DocumentRepository` of doctrine ?

Comment: No, this repository extends (default after created by php bin/console) from `Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository`

Comment: Did you have the class `ManagerRegistry`? If yes, try to get it in your constructor parameter. Then, you could get the repository with the method `getRepository(CLASS NAME OF ENTITY RELATED)`.

Comment: Yes, I have class `ManagerRegistry`, but I can put on object this class in constructor's repository, not in constructor command's console (because I have error with parameters). How I could from console's command get access to object's repository in another way ?

Comment: try to remove the service you have added for your command ( since it's already loaded by default configuration). And retry with `ManagerRegistry` as construct param. If it's not better, you could have acces to `$this->getContainer()->get(REPOSITYCLASS::CLASS);` but it could trigger some warning.

Answer (score 0):

A Symfony console Command class definition requires a `$name` parameter (which can be null) in the constructor. That name must then be passed back to the `parent::__construct($name);` call.

If the command does not require any dependency injected services (which would be added to the local constructor), then the `__constructor()` method definition in your class can be omitted to have it fall-back to the `Command` class that it is extending from.

```
class BotDataIpRangesCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:local:command-name';
    // other class fields

    public function __construct(MessageBusInterface $commandBus, string $name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->commandBus = $commandBus;
    }
    // other methods, including `configure()` & `execute()`
    // ...
```

Comment: [Symfony 5 docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#creating-a-command) mention nothing of the sort.